# Create multiple columns according to the values in column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to create new columns based on the values of the column.

| row_index | value | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | Server | Device Type |
| 512 | Server | Device Type |
| 512 | FMCG | Business |
| 1024 | CentOS | Device Type |
| 2048 | CentOS | Device Type |
| 1024 | Online | Business |
| 2048 | Offline | Business |
| 128 | ECommerce | Business |

TO THIS:

| row_index | DeviceType | Business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | Server | Ecommerce |
| 512 | Server | FMCG |
| 1024 | CentOS | Online |
| 2048 | CentOS | Offline |

I have tries to do this

```
pd.get_dummies(df.New)
```

but it is returning result in 0 and 1 also dropping the row_index column.